# VBA Array is empty after looping and putting cell values in it

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a macro I'm working on and it's suppose to loop through and store a cell's value into the array if the cells value equals IN. For some reason the array is empty. I'm new to VBA and suspect I might not be retrieving the cells values properly. Below is my code any assistance is appreciated thanks in advance.

Note the excel sheet the macro is being ran on does in fact have  content in those cells and several with the value IN.

```
    Option Explicit

'Variable Definitions ***********************************************************
Dim WorkbookSize As Long 'Var to hold number of rows in worksheet, used primarily to control loops
Dim newbook As Boolean 'Flag if new book was created correctly
Dim wb As Workbook 'var to hold workbook object
Dim TempPath As String 'var to hold local temp path to store newly created workbook
Dim i As Integer 'var used as counter for loops
Dim activeBook As String 'var to hold new workbook name


'Main Driver
Sub Main()
    WorkbookSize = size() 'Run function to get workbook size
    newbook = False
    Call create            'Run sub to create new workbook
    Call pull(WorkbookSize)              'Run sub to pull data
End Sub

'Get size of Worksheet
Function size() As Long
    size = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End Function

'Create workbook
Sub create()
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    TempPath = Environ("temp") 'Get Users local temp folder
    With wb
        .SaveAs Filename:=TempPath & "EDX.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        .ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly, WritePassword:="admin"
    End With
End Sub

'pull data
Sub pull(size)
    Dim code() As Variant
    ReDim code(size - 1)
    For i = 1 To size
    'Check code column fo IN and Doctype column for 810
        If Cells(i, 17).Value = "IN" Then
            code(i) = Cells(i, 17).Value 'store in array
        End If
    Next i
     Call push(code)
End Sub

'push data to new workbook
Sub push(ByRef code() As Variant)
    activeBook = "TempEDX.xlsm"
    Workbooks(activeBook).Activate 'set new workbook as active book
    Dim txt As String
    For i = 1 To UBound(code)
        txt = txt & code(i) & vbCrLf
        'Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = code(i)
    Next i
    MsgBox txt
End Sub
```

Comment: not your problem but you do not need to loop to fill: `code = Range(cells(1,17),cells(size,17)).value`

Comment: So you're saying the array `code()` is empty when `Pull` is done? or it's empty when it's passed to `Push`?

Comment: My guess is that your problem lies in the assumed active worksheet.  One should always declare the parent, either hard code or pass the worksheet to the functions.

Comment: Exactly. You create a workbook and that becomes active and that's where cells function is looking. You should create your workbook after you `pull` or you should fully qualify the `cells` call.

Comment: I recommend using F8 to step through and watch what's happening.  Your code is well formed, it may be that there's one step derailing it and stepping through will help you identify it.

Comment: @GisMofx & Scott Craner I rearranged the order in which the subs are called so that pull is done before create now I'm getting a subscript out of range error here: code(i) = Cells(i, 17).Value

Comment: That means `i` is greater than the ubound of your array

Comment: do not `Redim` the Array just assign the values directly as I stated in my first comment.  So three lines: `Dim code() As Variant`  `code = Range(cells(1,17),cells(size,17)).value` and `Call push(code)`

Comment: @scott Craner but I need to only store cells from this column if their value = IN

Comment: Okay add the IF but not the loop or the redim.

Comment: @Scott craner I just implemented a parentage by first storing the first active workbook in a variable. How would I use the if statement in code = Range(cells(1,17),cells(size,17)).value ? Thanks for the patience.

Comment: never mind on the array assignment

Comment: I missed that you want to test each cell

Comment: By storing the workbook in a variable does not dictate to which worksheet each of the Range Object belong.  It is the reason you got an empty array.  It was testing column 17 in the wrong sheet.  You need to specify the parent sheet to all Range object especially when working with multiple workbooks and worksheets.

Comment: The approach @ScottCraner is suggesting would be a performance increase as you only make one call to excel to get the data. It may not be measurable for 17 rows, but for larger sets, it could be significant. Last, you need to look through a 2d array to find your matching values.

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried looking into specifying a parent sheet to a range object but I'm not how it's done.

Comment: @GisMofx answer shows you how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fully qualify your calls to the `Cells` Property. Otherwise `Cells` uses the active workbook and worksheet. In your case, you've created a workbook before scanning in your pull method. So you're essentially looking at an empty worksheet.

Either create the new workbook AFTER you pull, or create a new Worksheet variable and set it at the beginning like:

```
dim currentWorksheet as Worksheet
set currentWorksheet = Activesheet
```

Then, you should pass `currentWorksheet` into the pull function and size function.

I would do something like this:

```
    Option Explicit

'Variable Definitions ***********************************************************
Dim WorkbookSize As Long 'Var to hold number of rows in worksheet, used primarily to control loops
Dim newbook As Boolean 'Flag if new book was created correctly
Dim wb As Workbook 'var to hold workbook object
Dim TempPath As String 'var to hold local temp path to store newly created workbook
Dim i As Integer 'var used as counter for loops
Dim activeBook As String 'var to hold new workbook name


'Main Driver
Sub Main()
    Dim currentWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set currentWorksheet = ActiveSheet

    WorkbookSize = size(currentWorksheet) 'Run function to get workbook size
    newbook = False
    Dim values()
    values = pull(currentWorksheet, WorkbookSize)               'Run sub to pull data
    push create(), values
End Sub

'Get size of Worksheet
Function size(sh As Worksheet) As Long
    size = sh.Cells(Rows.COUNT, "A").End(xlUp).row
End Function

'Create workbook
Function create() As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    TempPath = Environ("temp") 'Get Users local temp folder
    With wb
        .SaveAs Filename:=TempPath & "EDX.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        .ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly, WritePassword:="admin"
    End With

    Set create = wb
End Function

'pull data
Function pull(pullFromSheet As Worksheet, size) As Variant
    Dim code() As Variant
    ReDim code(size - 1)
    For i = 1 To size
    'Check code column fo IN and Doctype column for 810
        If pullFromSheet.Cells(i, 17).Value = "IN" Then
            code(i-1) = pullFromSheet.Cells(i, 17).Value 'store in array
        End If
    Next i
    pull = code
End Function

'push data to new workbook
Sub push(toWorkbook As Workbook, ByRef code() As Variant)
    'activeBook = "TempEDX.xlsm"

    'Workbooks(activeBook).Activate 'set new workbook as active book
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set newSheet = toWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim txt As String
    For i = 0 To UBound(code)
        txt = txt & code(i) & vbCrLf
        newSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = code(i)
    Next i
    MsgBox txt
    newSheet.Activate 'just to make your new sheet active for the user
End Sub
```

I moved the Push code outside of the pull code and also create functions instead of subs so you have good handles on the new objects you are creating.

Comment: @ScottCraner I agree with that approach, but I'm keeping the concept the same for the OP.  You still would need to loop through the array to find "IN"

Comment: Yes you would, and is why I deleted my comment, unless the OP is looping hundres of cells, probably not worth the time savings.

Comment: @ScottCraner some of the excel sheets this would be used on max out at 200 rows, not sure if there's a lighter way of checking that many cell values.

Comment: @AustinJones 200 values, you’re certainly ok with this method. If you have thousands of rows and multiple columns you should consider reading the whole range into an array.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm using your answer, but still getting a subscript error at code(i) = pullFromSheet.Cells(i, 17).Value not sure why.

Comment: @AustinJones I made a change. `code(i)` -> `c(i-1)`

Comment: *calls to the `cells` function* Is `Cells` a function?

Comment: @JohnyL, It's technically a "Property". I've corrected the language in my answer.

Comment: @GisMofx OK :-)

Comment: I noticed on the line For i = 1 To UBound(code) you start at one, which means you are skipping the first entry of code since on the line newSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = code(i) you are adjusting i for a 0 based array. you should change that first line to For i = 0 to Ubound(code)

Comment: @AustinJones Please see the fix above.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are not selecting the right sheet.

put a

```
Sheets("NAME_OF_SHEET").Select
```

before the for, like

```
Sub push(ByRef code() As Variant)
  activeBook = "TempEDX.xlsm"
  Workbooks(activeBook).Activate 'set new workbook as active book
  Dim txt As String

  Sheets("NAME_OF_SHEET").Select
  For i = 1 To UBound(code)
      txt = txt & code(i) & vbCrLf
      'Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = code(i)
  Next i
  MsgBox txt
End Sub
```

thanks